# Can you improve mySQL query with multiple GROUP BY's

Tags: mysql

So I set about finding out if I can / should increase the width of my site from 1000px to 1200px as apparently 90%+ people have screens above 1024px.

I wanted to group by the users but count them multiple times if they used different screens.
This gives me a list of all the sizes, but I only wanted distinct widths and count the amount of occurrences.

I got the results out I wanted but think the SQL query is pretty bad.

First question: Can you improve me sql query below:

```
SELECT width,COUNT(width) 
FROM (
  SELECT width 
  FROM user_hit 
  WHERE width>=1024 
  GROUP BY userId,width 
  ORDER BY width
) AS widths 
GROUP BY width 
ORDER BY COUNT(width) DESC
```

With the results I used PHP to determine the % of users with a screen above 1240px

Second question: Could you have achieve this result using only mySQL and no PHP

The result was 86.7% have screens bigger than 1240px

Third question: Should I increase the width of my website from 1000px -> 1200px projecting that soon, 9/10 users will get a better experience whilst 1/10 will have an annoying view?

I know I could display it differently for different users but I'd rather have a single view

Comment: You're not using `GROUP BY` correctly. I don't see the point of a sub-query here either.

Comment: I forgot to add, my site is information intensive and hence the extra width is valuable and will be made use of

Comment: Yes I don't think the SQL is very good, I'm asking for help improving it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need the subquery? The below query should be enogh

```
SELECT width, count(distinct userId) as count  
FROM user_hit 
WHERE width>=1024 
GROUP BY width 
ORDER BY width
```

Comment: I can confirm the following SQL did produce the same results as my above question and it is much better:  
  
    SELECT width, count(distinct userId) as count    
    FROM user_hit  
    WHERE width>=1024  
    GROUP BY width  
    ORDER BY count DESC

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

1) I think there is no need to improve your code because it does what you need.

2) Using PHP helps you with some results (OOP) such as getting the screen size of the users, browser type, OS type ...etc. but mySQL is related to storing those Data.

3) It depends on the number of users that registering on your website. also you need to get the % of weekly registered users. if the ratio is 1/10 for not having that size. yes it's better to increase the width of your website.

Regards